# shell script to replace subnet mask and default GW

Tags: linux, networking, bash, scripting

I need to create a shell script the gets as first parameter a subnet mask and as the second paramater a GW address.

something like this: "replace_IPs.sh 255.255.0.0. 10.0.0.254"   by running this line I will be able to put the new subnet mask and DW.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `ifconfig` for that?

`ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 gateway 192.168.0.254`

Comment: how do I put it in a script to receive argument of 192.168.0.1 and 255.255.255.0?

Comment: To just echo what's currently set you could use grep/awk and the like to parse the output of ifconfig, for example `ifconfig eth0 | grep "inet addr:"|awk '{print $2}'` or if installed you could also use `ifdata`. `ifdata -pa eth0` for IP address `ifdata -pn eth0` for netmask.